# Transpose of a 3×3 marix using lists and nested for loops

Tags: python-3.x

Transpose of a 3×3 marix using lists and nested for loops

I have assigned the elements of columns of th original marix to the rows of the new one to get the transpose.

```
a=[[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
b=[[0]*3]*3
for i in range(3):
 for j in range(3):
  b[i][j]=a[j][i] 
print(b)
```

Instead of getting transpose, all of the elements of the new matrix are the last element of the original matrix and it is all 9s.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Comprehension to instantiate a boolean 2D array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39015925/comprehension-to-instantiate-a-boolean-2d-array)

Comment: Change the initialization of `b` to `b=[[0 for _ in range(3)] for _ in range(3)]`